# How to update the prices from GCP in an interval manner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, gcloud-compute

I'm using `GCP`, i want to calculate Mounthly Cost & Hourly cost of using services, but i do not want to call GCP apis everytime.

Do you propose a solution on how to update the prices from `GCP` in an interval manner?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve? Do you want to get the pricing list?

Comment: Thanks to response, I want to know about time interval strategies also i should get the price of gcp services cost from api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [Google Cloud Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) in order to get a quick estimate of what your usage will cost on Google Cloud Platform.

For more information about Google Cloud Platform Pricing you may visit the link [here](https://cloud.google.com/pricing).

Regarding interval strategies, [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs#section-1) you may find popular solutions, top use cases, tutorials, and best practices to get started with using GCP.

I hope you find this information useful.